# Blender video not fully going in

Tags: video-sequence-editor

So I have this issue where when I insert a video file into blender, around 2/3 the video gets cut off (10 sec remains from the original 35ish seconds. However, the audio portion is all there, lasting the full 30ish seconds for some reason. Is there an easy remedy to fix this, as I have recorded multiple times and this issue still persists.

One thing to note, in my mail inbox, the video is always full and fine.

[image]
Edit:
[image]
These are the files. If I were to click on the now, they work perfectly. However, once I imported them to blender only the audio stays fully, half the video is deleted.

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file because you nearly gave any useful information. We can see no settings you made....

Comment: Ok edited the post

Comment: i asked for your .blend file. You inserted pictures/screenshots.

Comment: im pretty new to this still, let me know if thats what you mean

Comment: nearly ;) go to https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions. You have to drag/drop a file called  blabla.blend in there.

Comment: I put in the blender file and sent it here. Not sure if it worked

Comment: read the instructions carefully: you have to copy the result into your question....

Comment: is there a way to share the blend file without others being able to physically see the video?

Comment: Just take any other video in there which isn’t important and can be published. It’s just important that the same error/problem occurs.

Comment: its only that video clip for some really weird reason

Comment: then i have no idea how to help you, sorry